# sound controller

Tags: iphone

i am new to iphone....now i am doing one baby monitoring project...My part is controlling sound like if the baby was crying that automatically call to that baby's mom mobile number.....

So here how can i control the peak power which depends upon slider volume......please help me...
 and how can i make a phone call via programatically...please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a phone call or send an SMS without user interaction on a stock iOS device.  You might be able to use some sort of instant messaging service API instead.

You can use the AVAudioRecorder class to detect average sound levels.  If you want peak levels (and enough signal discrimination to help reject false positives), you will probably have to use a lower level API (Audio Queues) and some DSP code.

Answer (score 1):

You can make call by,
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:222-2211-111"]]

Comment: Ya he is right you can use the open url scheme to call,sms,message.....+1 for you for the right ans..